# Cobol Reading Record with a Table

Tags: record, cobol

I'm trying to display some data that I'm reading into a table. However, I keep getting the error:

> IN-FUND-NBR was not a uniquely defined name...Expected a reference-modification specification but found ")".

***EDIT: Okay, so I found the root of the problem. However, can't I still access `IN-FUND-NBR` as it sits? I tried the following, but it does not work:

```
DISPLAY "IN-FUND-NBR = " IN-FUND-NBR (MF-SALE-SUB) OF IN-MF-SALE
```

***END EDIT

I have the following record defined as follows:

```
 01  SALES-RECORD.                          
     05  IN-CITY-NAME           PIC X(20).  
     05  IN-CUSTOMER-NAME       PIC X(20).  
     05  IN-MF-SALE             OCCURS 4.   
         10  IN-FUND-NBR        PIC 9(2).   
         10  IN-PRICE-FLAG      PIC 9.      
         10  IN-PURCH-AMT       PIC 9(5)V99.
```

I'm trying to extract the first instance of IN-FUND-NBR by doing the following in a paragrah:

```
 PERFORM                                          
   VARYING MF-SALE-SUB FROM 1 BY 1                
     UNTIL MF-SALE-SUB > 4                        

       DISPLAY "Fund Number: " IN-FUND-NBR(MF-SALE-SUB)

 END-PERFORM.
```

Comment: FIXED IT! I had the subscript in the wrong area.

Comment: Perfect example of the confusion it can cause. Doesn't help that you can use either `OF` or `IN` as well. The next person who has to pick up your program will appreciate it if you've made the names unique. Note that an accurate reading of my answer would have saved you some time, but, really, for emphasis **`make your data-names unique!`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your program you have `IN-FUND-NBR` defined more than once. The other definition(s) may be in a copybook, or something you have coded yourself without realising. The compiler discards the reference to the field.

The second diagnostic message about the reference-modification is because having discarded the reference to your data-name the compiler then encounters the opening parenthesis and your subscript. This message will disappear when you correct the problem.

Either, ensure that the data-names are unique. Or, in the nutty situation that this is not possible, you have to use `qualification`. You do this by using IN or OF and referencing a higher level data-name.

From what you have shown:

```
DISPLAY "Fund Number: " IN-FUND-NBR OF SALES-RECORD (MF-SALE-SUB)
```

should work.

Although you can use `qualification`to get around the problem, many are like me and find it a complete waste of time and patience, and others, especially beginners, find it a source of confusion. Try your best to always have unique data-names.

Comment: Ahh yes, that is the problem. I figured it was something like that but I couldn't track it down. Turns out one the of copy books I'm using has IN-FUND-NBR already defined. Thanks!